# How to Disable `back` and `forward` button of the browser window

Tags: ember.js

In my applicaiton, I requried couple of things to be added.

1. No forward/Back Browser button should work for reach a hash.
2. Instead of brower back forward, there should be a back and forward button has to added in the applicaiton itself.

how to achive this both?
I am looking for a component to use globally for both 2 requriements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the native back/forward buttons of the browser in Ember.js is quite unusual but could possibly be achieved by using the [`NoneLocation`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.NoneLocation) class. To enable that open the `config/environment.js` file of your app and change the `locationType` property to `none`.

If you want to display back/forward buttons in your app you can use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) and specifically `window.history.back()` and `window.history.forward()`

Comment: But I use `history` instead of `none`.